# ¿Como "parsear" un archivo XML?

Tags: java, android

mi problema es el siguiente:

En mi proyecto de android estoy utilizando una API que brinda datos sobre la predicción meteorológica de una ciudad, dichos datos los recupero en un archivo XML; mi problema radica en que no logro "separar" los datos por etiqueta para poder manipularlos el condigo es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Descarga dc = new Descarga();
    dc.execute("");


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



 private class Descarga extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

    private String xml;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public Descarga(){
        xml = "";
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        xml = getXmlFromUrl("http://api.meteored.mx/index.php?api_lang=mx&localidad=22299&affiliate_id=do2kuih35e2g&v=2");

        return null;
    }


     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.isIndeterminate();
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    //En este método mediante el Toast se puede observar los datos si son 
    //recuperados
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resut){
        dialog.cancel();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,xml,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getData(xml);
        super.onPostExecute(resut);
    }

     private String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
         String sxml ="";
         try {
             DefaultHttpClient clienteHttp = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost postHttp = new HttpPost(url);
             HttpResponse respuesta = clienteHttp.execute(postHttp);
             HttpEntity entidad = respuesta.getEntity();
             sxml = EntityUtils.toString(entidad,"utf-8");

         }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex){

         }catch (ClientProtocolException ex){


         }catch (IOException ex){

         }
         return sxml;
     }

     /*Este es el metodo donde quiero recuperar los datos pero no lo consigo
       ya verifique que el archivo si lo esta recuperando */

     public void getData(String x){

         XmlPullParserFactory factory  = null;
         XmlPullParser parse = null;
         String texto = "";
         try{
             factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
             parse = factory.newPullParser();
             parse.setInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(x.getBytes("utf-8")),null);

             int evenType = parse.getEventType();

             while(evenType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                    String tagName = parse.getName();

                    switch (evenType){
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            texto = parse.getText();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,texto,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("20170921")){
                                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textday);
                                text.setText(""+parse.getAttributeValue(null,"value"));
                            }

                            break;
                        default:

                            break;
                    }
             }

         }catch (Exception e){}
     }


 }
}
```

EL archivo XML que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
http://api.meteored.mx/index.php?api_lang=mx&localidad=22299&affiliate_id=do2kuih35e2g&v=2
```

*Agradezco a quien me pueda apoyar.*

Comment: Existen diferentes bibliotecas que hacen eso... te recomiendo por simplicidad JDOM http://www.jdom.org/

Comment: En java existen distintos parsers de XML, uno asociado a eventos el cual no crea ninguna estructura de datos y el otro que guarda los estados y crea una estructura tipo árbol, los parsers son SAX y DOM respectivamente.  [leer más](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/what-is-the-difference-between-sax-and-dom)

Comment: No indicas que problema tienes, porque no realizas debugging para revisar donde provoca el problema. El uso de saxparser no es muy común actualmente, la mayoría de las apis también entregan datos en formato .json.

Comment: Olvida lo que comenté acerca de .json veo que esta API se quedó en la prehistoria, por cierto las clases DefaultHttpClient , HttpPost etc son de apache las  cuales ya son obsoletas en Android, usa HttpUrlConnection.